# Bundle Display Name Max Length

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

What is the maximum length of an iPhone App name (bundle display name, shown below the app on the iPhone home screen) that we can use without an ellipsis "..." being added?

Comment: in the market, on the home screen?

Comment: Based on the selected answer, it seems the asker means the `bundle display name`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no restriction upon the iphone app name length.

Answer (score 0):

It can be as long as you want. But to be displayed correctly on the homescreen it will be truncated from the middle and appear like this

"Your Great App Name" will be truncated to "Your Gre..Name"