# what is the maximum length the iPad application name can be?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Please anyone clarify me what should be the max-min length of the iPad/iPhone application can be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the max length of iPhone App Name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897936/what-is-the-max-length-of-iphone-app-name)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The length that it's technically allowed to be is a lot longer than you should make it. The reason being iOS will abbreviate the name on the home screen if it won't fit in the space available, for example "Really Long Title" might display as "Reall...le".

I say 'might' as iOS does not use fixed-width text. The only way to see what works is by trying it and seeing what works.

Finally, the display name is not necessarily the same as the application's name. For example, both the full and free versions of my app use the same display name, though they have different names in the App Store.

Comment: I have a paid version and a free ("lite") version.

Answer (score 68):

Forget calculating pixels. I found that the best method is renaming a folder in iOS to find out how iOS handles icon names. Please be aware that there can even be differences between devices! So an iPad icon name can be longer than an iPod icon name.

Comment: Ingenious, I didn't even think about testing with folder names!

Answer (score 41):

About `12 letters` but it depends on the width of each individual letter (**w** takes more room than **i**). And here I am talking about the `display name` of the app (shown under the icon on the iPad).

Answer (score 6):

There is no limit on the length of application as such. It can be 12,14,16 ...all depends on which characters are present in your app name  like W,Z will take much space than i,j . That means your app name appearing in the screen doesnot depend on the length of your name, it simply depends on the width of the screen that each character takes. And usually number will take much space than character. Try out with "iiiiiiiiiiiiii" on your app name and similar length of name with other charcaters.

Answer (score 1):

There are two app name lengths to be concerned with:

1. the length of the string visible under the app icon on a device's screen
2. the maximum length iTune Connect allows for app names

The first is addressed above and the advice to experiment with a folder name is the most useful though bear in mind the result is not guaranteed on all devices in all accessibility modes.

For the iTunes Connect case Apple now points you to the [App Store Product Page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/product-page/) to address this and they say:

> The length of your app name is limited to no longer than 50 characters. Notice how your app name will appear on the App Store for each device, including each version of iPhone, iPad, and Apple TV. We recommend keeping your app name to around 23 characters or less for optimal presentation on every device. Long names may be truncated, which means users will not see all the characters.

Answer (score 1):

As at Oct 2018:

"The name of your app as it will appear on the App Store. This can't be longer than 30 characters."  iTunes Connect

So 30 Characters max now (reduced from 50 historically)

Comment: Only 14 characters allowed to my app including space.